# Linux device driver buffering strategy

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Lets assume that I have an external device that is constantly pushing data into a small buffer in my driver. I'm using a wait queue where an interrupt handler wakes up a waiting user process (similar to *LDD (3rd edition) - Implementing a Handler*).

```
irq_handler_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{

 flag = 1;
 wake_up_interruptible(&wq);

return  IRQ_HANDLED;
}

ssize_t my_read(struct file *dev, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)

{

        wait_event_interruptible(wq, flag != 0);
        flag = 0;
        copy_to_user(usr_buf, drv_buf, count);

}


/***********************User program***********************/

while(1)
{    
    read(fid, buffer, size);

    //do stuff with data

}
```

The user program calls read and it waits till the interrupt gets new data from the external device. Since the external device may push data at a faster than this code can execute, what mechanisms can I use to ensure data is not overwritten before the user program copies it? Would a ring buffer like structure work here? Its not clear how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: How do your drv_buf get data? copy_to_user(usr_buf, drv_buf, count) should be copy_to_user(buf, drv_buf, count) .

Comment: *"what mechanisms can I use to ensure data is not overwritten before the user program copies it?"* -- Essentially the driver can only buffer as much as it can until there is buffer overrun.  A (statically allocated) ring buffer (as proposed in an answer) only can only postpone the overrun when the (ring) buffer is under-sized.  A well-written driver will be able to detect and report such a condition.  Even dynamically-allocated buffers maybe insufficient to cope with a "slow" reader.  IOW you do have to ensure that userspace can keep up with arriving data for at least some averaged rate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a ring buffer would work.

You simply have to fill the buffer from the interrupt handler and you will read it from the `my_read` callback.

A really naive and really really inefficient implementation could be (untested):

```
static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
        struct my_dev *dev = dev_id;

        buf[buf_wr] = read_device(dev);
        buf_wr++;

        if (buf_wr >= BUFSIZE)
                buf_wr = 0;

        wake_up(&wq);
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *ubuf,
                             size_t sz, loff_t *ppos)
{
        int n, ret;

        ret = wait_event_interruptible(wq,
                                buf_wr != buf_rd);
        if (ret)
                return ret;

        n = buf_wr - buf_rd;
        if (n < 0)
               n += BUFSIZE;

        n = min(count, n);
        ret = copy_to_user(ubuf, buf, n);
        buf_rd += n;

        if (buf_rd >= BUFSIZE)
                buf_rd -= BUFSIZE;

        if (ret)
                return ret;

        *ppos += n;
        return 1;
}
```

You may also want to use DMA or mmap or both to get something more efficient.

Comment: when more than two users can access the ring buff,it must protect by some synchronous primitive, means in the interrupt handler-irq_handler, can sleep?

Comment: User space signal is equivalent of interrupt in the linux kernel

Yes you can use the ring buffer mechanism. But you need to use kernel synchronization method to protect the data

Comment: Yes, you definitively have to use proper locking (here, a mutex is probably enough). As said, this is a really simple implementation,

Comment: Use of `kFIFO` mechanism might be efficient.